# How to subscribe to a Server-Sent Event server using cpp-httplib?

Tags: c++, http, curl, lib-http

I have a C++ code using `CURL` that subscribes to an Server-Sent Event server.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

// Callback function to handle SSE events
size_t handle_event_data(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* user_data) {
    // Process and handle the SSE event data here
    std::string event_data(static_cast<char*>(buffer), size * nmemb);
    std::cout << "Received event: " << event_data << std::endl;
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main() {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        // Set the SSE server URL
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:1234/event1");

        // Set the callback function to handle SSE events
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, handle_event_data);

        // Perform the SSE request
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to connect to SSE server: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize libcurl" << std::endl;
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

It subscribes perfectly to the server and receives the data as soon as the server produces an event.

I am trying to do the same thing using [`cpp-httplib`](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib.git). I have the following code but exits after receiving the first data.

```
#include <httplib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    httplib::Client("http://localhost:1234")
            .Get("/event1", [&](const char *data, size_t data_length) {
                std::cout << string(data, data_length);
                return true;
            });

    return 0;
}
```

Does `cpp-httplib` provide a similar capability to the one in `CURL`?